# I have trouble with my SESSION that change when i insert somethnig with POST

Tags: php, forms, session

I have some trouble with code below, what does is to put `$level` in a `$_SESSION` and i don't know how it do that. This `$level` replace my user `$_SESSION['level']` and then he is logged out.

```
<?php
session_start();

if( $_POST['action'] == 'Add' ) {

    $level = $_POST['level'];

?>

<form action="<?php $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]; ?>" method="post" >

    <input type="text" name="level" value="" placeholder="Level" /><br />

    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="Add" />
    <input type="submit" value="Add user" />
</form>
```

Comment: check `register_globals` value via `phpinfo();`

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the most common issue with the session variable is forgetting `session_start()` in the top of your document. You have actually put `session_start()` where it belongs, **but you have forgotten to define your session variable** :)

This is how it's done.

```
$_SESSION['level'] = $_POST['level'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();

if( $_POST['action'] == 'Add' ) {

    $_SESSION['level'] = ($_POST['level']) ? $_POST['level'] : null;
}

?>
```

Then you can assign it like so:

```
$level = isset($_SESSION['level']) ? $_SESSION['level'] : null;
```

Also, I recommend processing inputs with a Class, here's a basic one:

```
<?php
class Form
{
  public static function post($input)
  {
    return ($_POST[$input]) ? $_POST[$input] : false;
  }
}
?>
```

Then when you have a form you won't get a undefined variable, you can use it like:

```
Form::post('inputname');
```

**or**

```
if(Form::post('inputname') == 'add'):
  //passed
endif;
```

*Please note: pseudo code*

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean putting the `$level` into `$_SESSION['level']`. You could see the $_SESSION variable as a array where you have to give the key a value.
In your case

```
$_SESSION['level'] = $_POST['level']
```